# what is the logic for a web crawler to click on specific elements on the webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, web-crawler

I have written a crawler application which opens the given webpage and gets the HTTP Requests and stores in into excel sheet.

Now, I have some buttons for which I have binded click events using jQueries, (or you can think of onClick events for buttons). Now what could be the logic, to let my crawler click on these buttons and get the HTTP Requests and do same thing as I told earlier.

So to put it simply, how do I let my crawler to click on the buttons?

Comment: I don't think this is a simple thing. To do this, your crawler has to be able to understand and execute javascript. I think you need a headless browser for that http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: That is unless the buttons are simple hyperlinks. I'm actually a bit confused by the wording of "*... gets the HTTP Requests...*" - not sure what to understand from it

Comment: @Alexander : Let's take an example, I opened stackoverflow.com using my crawler, I get the HTTP Requests like http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js, and #n number of elements will load while the browser is rendering the webpage. So my crawler take this (from Fiddler debugger) and pushes to excel sheet. My problem is on loading somthing, my crawler can do, but how should I make my crawler click on the specific links?

Comment: @KhanhTO Thanks for the suggestion, can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you will have to make a crawler that can understand and parse javascript.
2. Even if you are able to do that, It depends on the implementation of click function/OnClick    if you will be able to get the link
   from it. 
       e.g. Links given through document.location can be understood but it will be very difficult to understand if a link is generated
   through an ajax call.

This is the primary reason why SEO content on a site is not loaded through javascript

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, exactly that's my problem. I want my crawler to go the website and product page and then add product to the cart, i.e. click on the "add too cart" button. How do I make my product click on add to cart?